# Gmaps issues on jupyter notebook

Tags: google-maps, jupyter

I load gmaps package in python.
However when in Jupyther notebook I type command :

```
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key="AI")
data = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset("taxi_rides")*
```

I have this error message:

```
*AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets'*
```

Does someone knows what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late to the party, but you are not importing the correct module:

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets # You also need to import this!

gmaps.configure(api_key="AI")
data = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset("taxi_rides")
```